# Binary labels (10 binary digits and each of the binary numbers in the set must differ for the other by at least 6 digits)

Tags: graph-theory, coding-theory

I ask a question previously about [binary labels](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4583375/binary-labelling).  I want to thank those who answered.  It was
very helpful.  I have a follow up question.  According to one of the answers I received it
said that if you have 10 binary digits it is possible to find 6 different binary numbers so that
each of the binary numbers differs from the 5 other binary numbers in at least 6 places.  I have
spent some time trying to accomplish this.  Does anybody have know how to do this.
Thanks for listening.

Comment: What you are describing is basically a binary code of length 10 with a Hamming distance of at least 6. So you could look up "Hamming distance", "Singleton-bound", and "Plotkin-bound" for further information.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 6 binary numbers with 10 digits so that any two numbers differ by six digits.
0000000000
1111110000
1110001110
1001101101
0101011011
0010110111

I did it by starting off with 000000000 and 111110000 and then
made a list of all the numbers that differed from these by 5 digits.
I picked what I thought was a likely guess for the next number and
made list of all the number that differed from these three numbers by
5 digits.  Call this set S.  Then I computed all the pairs of numbers
in S that differed by at least 5 digits.  Now I had a list several lists
of numbers that differed by at least 5 digits.  Then I looked for pairs
that shared a common number until I found two pairs that shared one number
and the remaining two numbers differed by at least 5 digits.  Now I had
a list of 6 binary numbers with nine digits that differed by at least 5
digits.  Then I added a new digit at the beginning where the digit was 0
if the number of 1's was even and 1 if the number of ones was odd.
I am sure there is a faster way to do this.